# How to get a background image of a table with no ID with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a backround image from a table but this table has no ID, it just says "" to the ID. All the functions to get the images that I've found ask for the 'tableid' but none of them work. :(

To be more specific about the problem, I need to check if this background image has a specific name, if so, I'll need the text of this table. But I can't get the text without knowing how to identify which table has that image on the background.

Any ideas?

Just editing to set a code (yes, it's a beginner code...)

```
var a = 44
var b = ""
var c = ""

for (i=0; i < a; i++)
{
    b = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].getAttribute("background")
    if b = "common/imgs/tabfade1.gif" 
    {
        c = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[i].getProperty("textContent")
    }
}
return c;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: You should provide an example of HTML.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks for all responses.

Comment: I'm trying something really simple....

Comment: var a = 44
var b = ""
var c = ""

for (i=0; i < a; i++)
{
 b = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i].getAttribute("background")
 if b = "common/imgs/tabfade1.gif" 
 {
  c = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[i].getProperty("textContent")
 }
}
return c;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have those tables with different backgrounds:

```
<table style="background: url('/file/Fw7FiAU/0b3f6fce-b461-488c-bb6e-cc92987cf6fb.jpg') no-repeat center center;"><tbody><tr><td>hey</td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
    <table style="background:url('/file/Fw7FiAU/teki.jpg') no-repeat center center;"><tbody><tr><td>hi</td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
    <table style="background:url('/file/Fw7FiAU/beki.jpg') no-repeat center center;"><tbody><tr><td>ho</td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
    <table style="background:url('/file/Fw7FiAU/yuli.jpg') no-repeat center center;"><tbody><tr><td>hiya</td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

Use any element selector depending on browser support - e.g.  "getElementsByTagName" etc. For this example I have used "querySelectorAll" .Use the "getComputedStyle(tables[i],null)" to grab the background style and  check for the desired image name in order to identify which table is the one you need.

```
var tables= document.querySelectorAll('table');
for(var i=0;i<tables.length;i++){
if(window.getComputedStyle(tables[i],null).background.match(/yuli/i)){
/*do what you have to do with this table*/
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(tables[i],null).background);
//console outputs the style: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://****************/file/Fw7FiAU/yuli.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / auto padding-box border-box
}
}
```

Modify the style selector accordingly if it is background-image.

Cheers

Comment: Looks a way more sofisticated of what I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an `id` attribute to select elements using JavaScript. You can do stuff like selecting all tables on the page, or the second one, or table with a given class etc.

A great way to do that would be [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript library for querying and interacting with the DOM.

EDIT:

Here is a simple example, that uses jQuery to select all tables and logs their background-image css property to the browser's console. Hopefully you can use this as a starting point:

```js
$('table').each(function(index, table){
  
  var bgImage = $(table).css('background-image');
  console.log('bgImage: ' + bgImage);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style="background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);">
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td>eee</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td>aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td>eee</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td>eee</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    <td>eee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but I barely understand jQuery. :)